# Error en el código de mi app al cambiar de compilador de c++

Tags: c++

Desarrollé una aplicacion en c++ builder 6 e implemente una clase de personalización de la libreriá map.
Ahora ejecuto ese mismo código en RAD Studio 10.3 c++Builder 10.3 y me da error.

mi código:

```
#include <map>
template < class Key, class T>
class tMapaSTL : public std::map<Key,T>
{
        std::map<Key,T>::iterator puntero;
     public:
        T& DatosPosicionActual(){return (*puntero).second;}
        Key LlavePosicionActual(){return (*puntero).first;}
        bool BuscarPorDato(T elem);
        bool BuscarPorLlave(Key llave){return (puntero=find(llave))!=end();}

        void Proximo(){puntero++;}
        void Anterior(){puntero--;}
        bool Final(){return puntero==end();}
        bool Principio(){return puntero==begin();}
        void SituarseAlFrente(){puntero=begin();}
        void SituarseAlFinal(){puntero=end();}

        T& operator*(){return (*puntero).second;}

        tMapaSTL& operator = (tMapaSTL &);
        void Insertar(T elem){insert(elem);}
        void EliminarPorLlave(Key llave){erase(llave);}
        void EliminarPorDato(T  elem);
        void EliminarPosActual(){if (puntero != end()) erase(puntero);}
        void Limpiar(){clear();}
        void Vaciar(){clear();}
        int Cantidad(){return size();}
};
```

Error en el c++ Builder 10.3 Rad Studio:

```
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(157): no matching function for call to 'end'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(161): no matching function for call to 'end'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(162): no matching function for call to 'begin'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(163): no matching function for call to 'begin'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(173): use of undeclared identifier 'clear'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(174): use of undeclared identifier 'clear'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(175): use of undeclared identifier 'size'
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(154): no member named 'second' in
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(154): no member named 'second' in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te está diciendo que no encuentra `end`, `begin`, `clear`, `size` y `second`.

Tines las siguientes soluciones:

1. Anteponer `this->` a las funciones que no encuentra para solucionar el problema:

   ```
   // ...
   bool Final(){return puntero==this->end();}
   //                           ^^^^^^
   bool Principio(){return puntero==this->begin();}
   //                               ^^^^^^
   void SituarseAlFrente(){puntero=this->begin();}
   //                              ^^^^^^
   void SituarseAlFinal(){puntero=this->end();}
   //                             ^^^^^^
   // ...
   ```
2. Traer al ámbito de la case las funciones que no encuentra:

   ```
   template < class Key, class T>
   class tMapaSTL : public std::map<Key,T>
   {
       using base = std::map<Key,T>;    // Alias como 'atajo' al tipo.
       typename base::iterator puntero;
   public:

       using base::begin; // Traer 'begin' a este ámbito.
       using base::end;   // Traer 'end' a este ámbito.        
       using base::clear; // Traer 'clear' a este ámbito.
       using base::size;  // Traer 'size' a este ámbito.
   // ...
   ```

Personalmente, yo no aplicaría ninguna de las dos soluciones ya que **no debes heredar de los contenedores estándar**. La clase base necesita un destructor virtual para evitar fugas de memoria y los contenedores estándar no lo tienen ya que estos objetos no están diseñados para ser heredados.

Lo que tienes que hacer es re-diseñar toda tu clase para que en lugar de heredar, contenga un miembro del contenedor que necesitas:

```
template < class Key, class T>
class tMapaSTL // ¡¡SIN HERENCIA!!
{
    using contenedor = std::map<Key,T>; // Atajo al tipo del contenedor interno.
    contenedor datos;                   // Contenedor interno.

        // Los iteradores son iteradores. LOS ITERADORES NO SON PUNTEROS.
        typename contenedor::iterator iterador;
     public:

        // La consulta de datos requiere también versión constante.
        T& DatosPosicionActual(){return (*iterador).second;}
        const T& DatosPosicionActual() const {return (*iterador).second;}

        // Evita copias usando referencias, la llave siempre es constante.
        const Key &LlavePosicionActual() const {return (*iterador).first;}

        // Las funciones que no modifican el estado, deben ser constantes.
        bool BuscarPorDato(T elem) const;
        bool BuscarPorLlave(Key llave) const {return (iterador=datos.find(llave))!=datos.end();}

        // Favorece pre-operar antes que post-operar.
        void Proximo(){++iterador;}
        void Anterior(){--iterador;}

        // Las funciones que no modifican el estado, deben ser constantes.
        bool Final() const {return iterador==datos.end();}
        bool Principio() const {return iterador==datos.begin();}
        void SituarseAlFrente(){iterador=datos.begin();}

        void SituarseAlFinal(){iterador=datos.end();}

        // La consulta de datos requiere también versión constante.
        T& operator*(){return (*iterador).second;}
        const T& operator*() const {return (*iterador).second;}

        tMapaSTL& operator = (tMapaSTL &);
        void Insertar(T elem){datos.insert(elem);}
        void EliminarPorLlave(Key llave){datos.erase(llave);}
        void EliminarPorDato(T  elem);
        void EliminarPosActual(){if (iterador!= datos.end()) datos.erase(iterador);}
        void Limpiar(){datos.clear();}
        void Vaciar(){datos.clear();}

        // Las funciones que no modifican el estado, deben ser constantes.
        int Cantidad() const {return datos.size();}
};
```

En el código de ejemplo que he compartido, además de solucionar el problema de la herencia inadecuada, he añadido las siguientes correcciones:

1. He renombrado el miembro `puntero`, los iteradores no son punteros.
2. Las funciones de acceso a datos, requieren una versión de sólo lectura (constante) y una versión de lectura+escritura (no constante).
3. Evita copiar datos devolviendo referencias.
4. Las funciones que sólo consultan datos deben ser de sólo lectura (constantes).
5. Favorece pre-operar el iterador frente a post-operarlo, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber por qué.